# Joining Two Query results on the basis of one column

Tags: mysql

I am having table structure something like this. table name is `z_notes`

`v_resident_fname` (Basically a name)

`i_communication_log` (Boolean value, contains 0 or 1, 0 indicates routine notes and 1 indicates critical notes)

`dt_note_created` (Date)

So what I need to do is, first I want all the names along with their count where `i_communication_log = 0` and `dt_note_created < 1332792382` and `dt_note_create > 1332792382` .

so the query for this is:

```
SELECT v_resident_fname as Name, COUNT( * ) AS Critical_Notes 
FROM z_notes
WHERE dt_note_created >1332792382
AND dt_note_created <1332892382
AND `i_communication_log` = 1
GROUP BY v_resident_fname
```

returns:

```
______________________
|Name |Critical_Notes|


| abc |      7       |

| xyz |      4       |
```

The other query is the same but i_communcation_log = 0

```
SELECT v_resident_fname as Name, COUNT( * ) AS Routine_Notes 
FROM z_notes
WHERE dt_note_created >1332792382
AND dt_note_created <1332892382
AND `i_communication_log` = 0
GROUP BY v_resident_fname

_____________________
|Name |Routine_Notes |

| abc |      3       |

| xyz |      4       |
```

I want to combine these two queries as one query on the basis of Name such that the end result is something like:

```
____________________________________
|Name |Critical_Notes|Routine_Notes|

| abc |      7       |     3       |

| xyz |      4       |     4       |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    v_resident_fname as Name,
    SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Critical_Notes,
    SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Routine_Notes
FROM z_notes
WHERE dt_note_created >1332792382
AND dt_note_created <1332892382
GROUP BY v_resident_fname
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 1 THE 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Critical_Notes, SU' at line 3

:(

Comment: Sorry, missed a comma at the end of the first select item, I've just editted it.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Routine_Notes),' at line 3

:(

Comment: Sorry again, the `CASE` syntax, documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html), wasn't exactly what I thought. I've fixed it.

Comment: Another error: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE) AS Critical_Notes, SUM(CASE i_communication_log WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 E' at line 3

Comment: That's VERY odd. It's pointing to the `CASE` from `END CASE`, but when we left that out it complained as well. What version of MySQL are you using? `CASE ... WHEN ... END CASE` is correct for version 5.1

Comment: Hmm, isn`t there any other way to do it? Joins or maybe Union?

Its 5.5.20

Comment: I've looked back at the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) and I was right the first time with the `CASE` statement syntax, so I've rolled back to that answer. You said - your second Error #1064 comment - that this failed, but looking more closely at the error message, the code fragment you quote isn't in the answer. Please will you try again. I'm sure you could do this using a `JOIN` or 'UNION' but for my money, this is a simpler solution, and I think would run faster than either.

Comment: Hmm, it does not work. :( gives the same error again. It says there is something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Please will you addd _exactly_ what you tried and the _exact_ error message to the question so I can try to diagnose what is wrong. Thanks.

Comment: The query the one above..

Error is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM z_notes WHERE dt_note_created >1332792382 AND dt_note_created <1332892382 G' at line 5

Comment: There is an extra comma in the select list which I have just removed.

Comment: That's exactly why I like to put the comma at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Six of one, half-a-dozen of the other

Comment: Good to hear! Sorry about all the typos on the way.